# Where are definitions of inbuilt C functions stored

Tags: c

Wikipedia Says:

> "Each header file contains one or more function declarations, data type definitions, and macros."

It says that the header file only contains declaration.So where are the definitions of any particular inbuilt function written? How it is accessed in any C program?

Comment: They are elsewhere. The definitions aren't made visible to the compiler to be compiled every single time; they have already been compiled beforehand into libraries to be combined with your code at link time. Your header files just tell the compiler: "here are some functions implemented elsewhere; let the linker find them".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Function definitions are present in header files itself. Let's say `printf` function it is stored in `stdio.h` header file. If you open that header file, you can find the function declaration on line 307

```
extern int __mingw_stdio_redirect__(printf)(const char*, ...);
```

And if you scroll down on line 377, you can find definition:

```
__mingw_stdio_redirect__

int printf (const char *__format, ...)
{
   register int __retval;

   __builtin_va_list __local_argv; 
   __builtin_va_start( __local_argv, __format);
   __retval = __mingw_vsprintf( __format, __local_argv );
   __builtin_va_end( __local_argv );
   return __retval;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The standard C library functions are provided in libraries along with your compiler and the rest of your toolchain.  For unix-like systems, that's usually in libraries called `libc` and `libm`.  `libc` is normally linked with your program by default.  `libm` sometimes is and sometimes isn't.

Comment: Surely that's only true for some C distributions (or operating systems), right?

Comment: Honestly I don't know what Microsoft does.  The real point is that the implementations are in libraries provided along with the compiler.

Comment: Replace "normally" with "in unix-like systems" and I'll be OK with that :)